# What is the difference between these icons in RTC source control?

Tags: rtc

In RTC source control, what is the difference between these two 'change set' icons :

[image]

[image]

In my setup both changes sets contain multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a, *active* change set.

But the second one is the [**current** change set](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/119107/scm-what-is-the-difference-between-and-active-and-current-change-set), that is the one you have last chosen to checkin in.

You can checkin in as many change set as you want, in order to group related changes together.

The "current change set" is marked in the Pending Changes view with a smaller blue triangle:

[image: https://jazz.net/forum/upfiles/capture_8.png]

From the [help page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v4r0m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_marking_change_set_current.html):

> Any change set that has not been completed can be modified by operations such as check in, move, undo, and remove; and is said to be an active change set.
>   Active change sets cannot be shared with other repository workspaces because they are not stable.
>   **In any workspace, there can many active change sets for a component, but only one can be the current change set**.
>
> If you have more than one active change set in a workspace, one of them is identified as the current change set (**the one in which all check-ins accumulate by default**).